# Wordpress timer methods

Tags: php, timer, wordpress, countdown

My Wordpress plugin has to make some changes in a file when I get a POST command and after some time revert the changes. I'm struggling in making the timer work. I am trying to use the EvTimer class. Any ideas how to make it work?

EDIT: It looks it doesn't find Ev Class and that is why it is not working. Is there a way to install/use the PECL extension/EV class if I don't have access to apache/php? Or maybe there's a way to use some different function instead of EvTimer to achieve the same functionality? Ty!

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
   if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {

   do_action('onchangeapi', new PostListener($_POST));
  }
} );

class PostListener {

private $valid = false;
private $pathToFile = "somefile.txt";
private $orgCode = "someCode";
private $noChangeColor = "#AAAAAA";
private $noChangeGradient = "#BBBBBB";
private $changeColor = "#123123";
private $changeGradient = "#345345";


public function __construct(array $postdata) {
    $this->valid = $this->validatePostData($postdata);

    if ($this->valid) {

        //changes some things in file
        $this->findAndReplace($this->pathToFile, $this->orgCode, $this- >changeColor, $this->changeGradient);

        //reverts it after some seconds. 
        new EvTimer(15, 0, $this->findAndReplace($this->pathToFile, $this- >orgCode, $this->noChangeColor, $this->noChangeGradient));

    }

 }

private function findAndReplace($file, $code, $changeToColor, $changeToGradient) {
//makes some changes in file
}

private function validatePostData(array $postdata) {
//validates the postData
}
```

}

Comment: The file remains the same even after the seconds set in timer. I guess I am not using the timer correctly.

Comment: It looks my PHP doesn't find the Ev class. Is there a way to install it if I don't have access to apache/php?